# Is it possible to get the contents of the system tray via command line command?

Tags: xfce, desktop-environment, gtk, panel

After seeing how many custom status bar implementations like Polybar seem to use some existing widget for displaying system tray icons I'm not too hopeful with this but would it be possible to get the metadata (icon, software name etc.), which is displayed normally in desktop environment's panel's system tray, programmatically via either some API or command line command?

Since the tray itself seems to get this info from somewhere I figured it should be possible but I don't know where to look into. I checked the XFCE sys-tray's source briefly but didn't figure it just yet since I have no experience with GTK apis. Looked like it uses some socket api.

I'd like to display system tray icons but stylize them and position them with more freedom than the system tray widget(?) allows.

If it matters, in my case I'm using XFCE desktop environment on Manjaro.